# Extracting data from a data frame with conditions

Tags: r, dataset

Given the first data frame consisting of 4 columns

```
libId    studId    year    freq
 1000      3       2002     3
 1000      34      2002     2
 1000      52      2004     9
 1001      17      2003     5
 1001      34      2003     1
.
.
.
.
```

If I were to extract only data with maximum frequency based on year for each libId this would be the desired output.

```
 libId    studId    year    freq
 1000      3       2002     3
 1000      52      2004     9
 1001      17      2003     5
.
.
.
.
```

So far I've tried

```
data2<- by(data1, c(data1[c(1,2,3)]), function(df) max(df$Freq))

data2 <- as.data.frame(as.table(data2))
```

But my output is incorrect:

```
libId    studId    year    freq
 1000      3       2002     3
 1000      34      2002     2
 1000      52      2004     9
 1001      17      2003     5
 1001      34      2003     1
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good [summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25314565/9291522) on StackOverflow from the user EDi that I'm referring to. Basically, what you want to do is group the values by year and then select the maximum frequency of each group:

```r
# with dplyr
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(freq = max(freq))

# data.table
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[ , max(freq), by = year]
```

Check out the linked answer for further possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the task, first attach data stored in a `df` object, then use aggregate function:

```
attach(df)    
aggregate(freq ~ year, FUN=max)
```

which **outputs**:

```
  year freq
1 2002    3
2 2003    5
3 2004    9
```

But if you want to show complete data frame without sorting, you must do an index vector like:

```
ind <- sort(aggregate(freq ~ year, FUN=function(x) {which(df$freq==max(x))})$freq)
```

Next:

```
df[ind,]
```

**Output**

```
  libId studId year freq
1  1000      3 2002    3
3  1000     52 2004    9
4  1001     17 2003    5
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using subset function.
Below is an example.

```
output_df<- subset(input_df, freq>= 3)
```